# Glitchy widths when using transitions on pseudo element with background images in Bootstrap grid

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Hard to explain what I'm seeing. Included a fiddle to show. When I'm hovering over some of the divs, there is a 'glitch' on the edge of other divs in the grid. Almost seems as if the width is changing for a second then back again. Again, it's difficult to explain. Please see the fiddle in 2 or 3 column layout.

https://jsfiddle.net/riegersn/q2g9gxk3/3/

```
.project::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -100%;
  top: 0;
  width: 200%;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: left center;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-size: contain;
  background-image: inherit;
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-out;
}

.project:hover::before {
  transform: translateX(50%);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that's a fun one.

I will be totally honest and say I am not really sure *why* this works (so maybe someone else will come along with a better answer), but adding `transform-style: preserve-3d` fixed the problem for me:

```
.project::before {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this does fix it, odd. Hopefully, someone else will elaborate.